# How to update a row depending on a condition

Tags: php, updating

I try to update a row in my database. i receive no error but the update does not happend

```
$sql = "UPDATE calendar_events 
        SET event_title='".$_POST["naam"]."' 
        WHERE id ='($event_id)'";
```

problem is by variable $event_id. If i place a nummber in place of $event_id ( WHERE id =6)
then it is ok and i have my update but any  he do not accept any variable
I did change a lot of things. The type of variabls id and  $event_id  are the same. De value of the id and $event_id are de same . i did try with $event_id, and '".$event_id."'. every thing is ok
and no erroror from database bat the update do not happen.
can someone help me
thanks

Comment: And of course please filter your naam before entering it into the sql string!

Comment: Try printing the sql onscreen, and if the sql is correct, execute it on the Database you are working on, to see if the query is correct for the database.

Comment: What is the type of the id column?

Comment: Use `WHERE id = '$event_id' ";` instead. Parentheses are mostly used when there is more than one value. Plus, using `'".$_POST["naam"]."'` is not considered a safe calling method.

Comment: I also noticed in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957009/update-the-single-row-in-php-row-with-php) that you are using `MySQL_` - I strongly suggest that you move over to `MySQLi_` or PDO. Mostly for security reasons. Your site/DB stands at being hacked if you continue using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$sql = "UPDATE calendar_events 
        SET event_title='".$_POST["naam"]."' 
         WHERE id ='$event_id'";
```

Otherwise, you are comparing it with (1), (2) or whatever number it has, but with parenthesis.

UPDATE: and, of course, SANITIZE your $_POST variables!!!

Comment: I did try but no resault.

Comment: my query say dat it is happend if (!mysql_query($sql)) is true

Comment: This has something to do with the other question (OP) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957009/update-the-single-row-in-php-row-with-php I'm sure.

Comment: I am wondering if i use just a number in my condition then it is ok

Comment: Can you provide an example query?

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE calendar_events SET event_title='abc' WHERE id='$event_id'";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) { // voer SQL code uit

echo "not ok";
  return;
}
echo "OK"; 
} else {

Comment: if $event_id has a valid value, the query is OK, so it should work. Otherwise, you might have: permission problems, no equivalent $event_id values, misconfiguration of your PHP...